# Revising Armor Class for a Homebrew System

Tags: system-agnostic, homebrew

I have decided to create a Homebrew System loosely based off of Pathfinder. There is a Mechanic I would like to add in, but I haven't found any good references within the Exchange for:

1. Revising the Armor Class system to encompass the ability to dodge(evasion) & block/parry certain attacks and abilities. These should be stand alone from each other, as in evasion/ parry is rolled.

Comment: Do you want to roll them at the same time, always separately, or have an option?

Comment: I think a player will have a choice, but it is more likely gm's discretion based on the NPC's they are facing. Like I want to Evade that attack(given that it is ranged) something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Given that one is familiar with Palladium, but wants a core of 5E...

migrating the D&D AC system is easy. We add a touch AC, a dodge reaction, and a parry reaction. And, of course, a means of modelling Armor SDC...

- Touch AC = 10 + Dex Mod + Magic for medium.
- Armored AC = standard D&D 5E AC
- Armor SDC: 5x base AC would be a reasonable point to start from.

The way it works...

- D&D attack roll as normal...

  - if attack is < Touch AC, miss
  - if attack roll is > Touch AC, hit.
  - if attack roll is > Armored AC, hit is to HP; if not, hit damages SDC
- React

  - Option 1: D&D style fixed reactions

    - Parry: react to add Str Bonus (min 1) to both AC's. Add dex if using finesse weapon
    - Dodge: react to add Dex Bonus (minimum 1) to both AC's.
    - Roll with Punch/Fall/Impact: react to subtract Con modifier (min 1) from damage taken.
  - Option 2: Palladium style rolls

    - Parry: React to Make an weapon attack check: if higher than opponent's to hit, subtract your damage from theirs.
    - Dodge: React to make an Acrobatics check; if higher than attacker's roll, attack misses.
    - Roll with Punch/Fall/Impact: Make an Athletics check; if higher than attackers roll, damage is halved.
- Damage to SDC: recorded just like damage to hit points

  - While SDC above 0, provides full value
  - When SDC hits 0, it is reduced to Touch AC, and any leftover damage is applied to the Hit points.
  - A Mending cantrip repairs 1 SDC per casting, but only if SDC lost is less than half base.
  - a suitable toolset with materials repairs up to crafting roll points per 4 hours effort

D&D 5 at present always has a flat portion: the attribute modifier.

Comment: I'm looking for the Evasion/Parry/Block, in terms of reactions, to be stand alone. Like a player has a choice between allowing damage to hit the AC, or they can attempt to either deflect or move out of harms way. I should have clarified my question better....

Comment: Also, If i was to have some form of d&d, i'd probably use the 3.5e and not 5e, I dislike 5e, hence the creation of a homebrew that my current rp group likes

Comment: Noting that SDC = Structural Damage Capacity might be helpful for all readers who are not the querent, nor familiar with Palladium's system.  (I am reminded of Runequest's armor system now ... )

Answer (score -2):

Advanced Dungeons & Dragons changed your AC based on your armor type and the weapon's damage type making even light armor a better AC than heavy at times.

Big Eyes Small Mouth was the first of the d20 based systems that I saw where instead of a flat 10 AC (Defense) base, the defender would roll it.  Therefore, instead of "taking 10" on evading it was a test.

Quite frankly, the information you need to blend these two systems is already there.  You could argue that "1" from Pathfinder is worth 5% in Palladium and vice versa. so "+1 Evasion Bonus" becomes "+5% Evasion Bonus".

Comment: So having the player roll for Evasion and the like, rather than flat score?